# nested classes in java

Tags: java, nested-class

Could anyone please tell me why the code below doesn't work ?

```
public class NestedClassPrac {
    public static class Nested {
        public void sayHello() { System.out.println("First nested class~");}
        public static class LittleNested {
            public void sayHello() { System.out.println("this is why we are nested class");}
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nested a = new Nested();
        a.sayHello();
        LittleNested b = new LittleNested();
        b.sayHello();
    }
}
```

error msg:

```
NestedClassPrac.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class LittleNested

location: class NestedClassPrac
        LittleNested b = new LittleNested();
        ^

NestedClassPrac.java:13: cannot find symbol

symbol  : class LittleNested

location: class NestedClassPrac
        LittleNested b = new LittleNested();
                             ^
2 errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LittleNested` is only accessible through `Nested` class you can not access it directly without use of `Nested`.You can access inner static class same as you access any other static member of class (*i.e, method,variable*).

***For Example***

```
class X{
    static class Y{
        static class Z{
            Z(){
                System.out.println("Inside Z");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can create `Object` of `Z` like this as inner classes are *static*.

```
X.Y.Z obj=new X.Y.Z();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        Nested.LittleNested b = new Nested.LittleNested();
```

What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The following will compile:

```
Nested.LittleNested b = new Nested.LittleNested();
```

or you can import LittleNested

```
import <yourpackage>.NestedClassPrac.Nested.LittleNested;
```

Basically, you have access inside `main` to anything at the same hierarchical level inside `NestedClassPrac` without needing an import. That gives you access to `Nested`. However, `LittleNested` is not at the same level hierarchically; `LittleNested` is inside `Nested`. Therefore, you need an import.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because from the main method scope you need to refer to the LittleNested sub-inner class including the enclosing class name:

```
public class NestedClassPrac {
    public static class Nested {
        public void sayHello() { System.out.println("First nested class~");}
        public static class LittleNested {
            public void sayHello() { System.out.println("this is why we are nested class");}
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nested a = new Nested();
        a.sayHello();
        Nested.LittleNested b = new Nested.LittleNested();
        b.sayHello();
    }
}
```

From the main method only the Nested class can be referred. You can read about it at [Nested Classes - Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 0):

you should access like this:

```
 OuterClass.InnerClass1.InnerClass2...InnerClassN obj=new OuterClass.InnerClass1.InnerClass2...InnerClassN();
obj.method();
```